# Bulk Query with PK chunking enabled where is the location of the original batch when we read the BatchInfo[] from the Bulk Job Id

Tags: rest-api, query, bulk-api

For bulk query jobs if the job has PK chunking enabled, will the original batch (that contains the query when the subsequent batches are created) will be created  with the id as "0" in an BatchInfo List

For example if we have the following

```
 BatchInfo[] bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();
```

Will the Original Query Batch will always be in bListInfo[0] ? If not, how can this be ensured

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found.
The batch which will be returned with the createBatchFromStream() API is the "original" batch, and we need to wait for the state of this batch to be as "BatchStateEnum.NotProcessed", to make sure that all the batches have completed processing. 
The code method for doBulkQuery() is as follows

```
    public void doBulkQuery(BulkConnection bulkConnection) {

      try {   
            job.setObject(ObjectName);
            job.setOperation(OperationEnum.query);
            job.setConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.Parallel);
            job.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);

            job = bulkConnection.createJob(job);
            assert job.getId() != null;
            System.out.println("Job id is " + job.getId());

            ByteArrayInputStream bout = new ByteArrayInputStream(querySOQL.getBytes()); 
            BatchInfo pkChunkBatchInfo = bulkConnection.createBatchFromStream(job, bout);

            bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();

            int iBatchSleep =0;
            while( pkChunkBatchInfo.getState() != BatchStateEnum.NotProcessed)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                pkChunkBatchInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfo(job.getId(), pkChunkBatchInfo.getId());  

                iBatchSleep++;                  
                if(iBatchSleep > 600)
                    break;
            }

            bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();
            BatchInfo info = bListInfo[finalBatchCount];
            numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract++;

            String[] queryResults = null;

            for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) 
            {

                info = bulkConnection.getBatchInfo(job.getId(), info.getId());

                if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed) 
                {
                    QueryResultList list = bulkConnection.getQueryResultList(job.getId(),info.getId());             
                    queryResults = list.getResult();
                    break;
                } 
                else if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) 
                {
                    System.out.println("-------------- failed ----------" + info);                  
                    break;
                } 
                else if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.NotProcessed) 
                {
                    // The batch won’t be processed. If the job has PK chunking enabled, this state 
                    // is assigned to the original batch that contains the query when the subsequent 
                    // batches are created
                    //continue;
                    break;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("-------------- waiting ----------"  + info);               
                }

                Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(sleepTimeForBatchStatusLoop) * 1000);
            }

            if (queryResults != null) 
            {
                for (String resultId : queryResults) 
                {
                    InputStream resultStream = bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(job.getId(), info.getId(), resultId);
                    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultStream,"UTF8"));
                    String lineString = null;
                    lineString = lineReader.readLine();

                    if (lineString.equalsIgnoreCase("Records not found for this query"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Batch " + info.getId() + " - Records not found for this query");
                        continue;
                    }

                    while((lineString = lineReader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("lineString : " + lineString);
                        numberOfRecordsExtracted++;
                    }
                }
            }  
      } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
            aae.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    // Read the remaining batches
    while (!isQueryDone())
    {
        getMoreData();
    }

    // Print results
    System.out.println("Job id is " + job.getId());
    System.out.println("Number of batches created with chunkSize " +  setChunkSize + " is " + numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract);
    System.out.println("Number of total records extracted is " + numberOfRecordsExtracted);
    long finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    long elapsedTime = (finishTime - startTime)/1000000; 
    int seconds = (int)(elapsedTime / 1000) % 60 ;
    int minutes = (int)((elapsedTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int hours = (int)((elapsedTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    System.out.println("Time for processing is "+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}
```